# Multiple button to choose and information show on next scene javafx

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I have two scene. First scene is for users to click on the buttons with information, and the second scene is to display out the information.The problem I am facing now is that the second scene will only display the information of the last button.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96w0I.png)eg: When I click on the 1300(btnone)button the second scene will only show 1500(btnthree) button.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HG1w.png) So what should I do so that the second scene will show information only when the user clicks on to the button. Thank you

```
// Event Listener on Button[#btnhello].onAction
@FXML
public void handlehello(ActionEvent event) {
    // TODO Autogenerated
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/show.fxml"));
        Parent root=(Parent) loader.load();
        showController show=loader.getController();
        show.setText(name.getText());
        show.setTime(btnone.getText());
        show.setThree(btnthree.getText());
        Stage stage=new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no text field in the `show.fxml` for `setTime()` as per your image, so I think you need to add a text field in `show.fxml` and refer that field in the `setTime()` and that should do the trick.

If this does not solve the issue, post your full code here as well as `show.fxml`.